# How to extract vertically-written text (in Japanese style) from png files in R

Tags: r, image, text, ocr, cjk

I'm trying to extract text from old posters written with a mix of Korean and Chinese languages in a vertical format (from top to bottom, and from right to left), as in the image attached in the url link here:

http://library.nec.go.kr/neweps/ezpdfwebviewer/ezpdf/customLayout.jsp?contentId=2F6570646174612F455030362F45434D323030362F30312F45434D303132303036303239312F45434D303132303036303239315F30313431532E706466

I have two questions where any help would be greatly appreciated:

1. How can I extract text that was written vertically from top to bottom, and from right to left (rather than horizontally-written text from top to bottom and from left to right)?
2. How can I extract two languages at once (Korean and Chinese characters) from a png file?

What I have tried so far is something like:

```
library(tesseract)
library(magick)
tesseract_download("kor")
korean <- tesseract("kor")
pngfile <- pdftools::pdf_convert('/Users/R/USEFULRCODES/example2.pdf')
text <- tesseract::ocr(pngfile, engine = korean)
cat(text)
```

As above, I first downloaded the file from the link provided above as a pdf and converted it to a png file using the pdf_convert function. I then used the ocr function from the tesseract pacakge to extract the text. However, this reads the text in the wrong direction making the extracted text incomprehensible.

Comment: Perhaps you can try with `tesseract_download("kor_vert")`

Comment: Break this down into single questions at a time. Have you investigate Google Translate? It doesn't seem to have any difficulty coming up with Japanese to English translation on my iPhone.

Comment: Thanks @IRTFM but I don't need translations to English. I just need to extract the text in the images as is but couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: I think Google Translate will also allow capture of the original text.

Comment: Google Lens can detect vertical text; I just copied `人事의 말씀` from there. However, it didn't seem to detect some other parts of the text, like 閔耭植